# ¿Como instalar laravel 5.6 en un subdirectorio?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, error404

Necesito instalar laravel en una subcarpeta teniendo la siguiente estructura. 
Ruta:

```php
http://dominio/subcarpeta/
```

Por lo que tengo la siguiente estructura de carpetas:

parte_privada_de_laravel

```php
public_html
|__parte_publica_de_laravel
```

ya configure el index.php que esta en:

public_html

```php
|__ parte_publica_de_laravel
   |__ index.php
```

En las lineas necesarias:

```php
require __DIR__.'/../../parte_privada_de_laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../parte_privada_de_laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Con esto cuando cuando hago la petición a:

```php
GET http://dominio/parte_publica_de_laravel/
```

me carga perfectamente la vista de `welcome.blade.php` que viene configurada en `web.php`

Mi problema empieza cuando ejecuto el comando:

```php
php artisan make:auth
```

dado que cuando entro a la ruta:

```php
GET http://dominio/parte_publica_de_laravel/login
```

me manda la vista de un error 404:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

también pasa lo mismo cuando intento definir una nueva ruta:

```php
Route::get('/home', function(){
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Si entro a la ruta

```php
http://dominio/parte_publica_de_laravel/home
```

Tambien manda el error 404:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: Debes crear las vistas de login y home

Comment: No se que fue lo que paso pero hice un nuevo proyecto y funciono normalmente. Lo mas curioso es que tiene exactamente la misma estructura.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aqui te dejo un [mcve]

Comment: Podrías configurar todo esto de manera simple si tan solo redirigieras el dominio: `www.tu-dominio.com/directorio` en la configuración de Nginx o Apache hacia tu instalación de Laravel sin siquiera tocar el código del proyecto (salvo `app/config.php` para indicarle el la ruta). Te ahorras todo este problema. Pues -eventualmente- lo que has hecho te traerá algún que otro dolor de cabeza.